# Is there a way to get the Pyramid json renderer to output formatted, pretty printed, output?

Tags: python, json, rest, pyramid

I like my json output to be nicely formatted, even for a REST API. It helps when debugging, etc. The extra overhead is minimal, especially when using gzip

Is there anyway to tell the pyramid json renderer (i.e, this thing)

```
    @view_config(request_method='POST', renderer='json')
```

to output formatted, pretty-printed output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just figured it out myself. In my **init** I added

```
 from pyramid.renderers import JSON
 # ...
 config.add_renderer('prettyjson', JSON(indent=4))
```

and then I just do this in my view

```
   @view_config(request_method='POST', renderer='prettyjson')
```

Comment: Even better, you can override the existing `json` renderer by slightly modified `add_renderer` call
    config.add_renderer('json', JSON(indent=4))